# Defining a command on more than one line

Tags: key-bindings, functions

It seems like the `command` command expects a one line set of arguments. What is a good way to define a command from something longer?

I suppose defining a function with no argument and then calling the function from the command would work, but is that the standard, good,  way?

Comment: That, or using `\ ` at the start of the continuation line(s).

Comment: I personally prefer to define a function as `fun! s:my_fun()`, this will only be visible inside the current file (and is not "exposed" needlessly when running Vim). I don't like the `\ ` line-continuation and `|` to chain commands as I find them unreadable and awkward to deal with.

Comment: I'd say the function is the way to go indeed: I'm not sure it is possible to define a multiline command, but if it is I think that would be pretty "ugly"

Comment: Yes, it's possible to define a multiline command - you have an ("official") example at the end of `:h command-completion-custom` :)

Comment: Also, for the OP, your function can have arguments, and you can pass them from the command using (preferably) `<f-args>` (see `:h <f-args>`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When wondering about the standard, good way of writing something in VimL I usually check two main resources: the Vim documentation, which is extremely comprehensive and well written, and Steve Losh's blogs ([Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) and [Writing Vim Plugins](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2011/09/writing-vim-plugins/#be-pathogen-compatible)).

One approach to find examples in the Vim documentation is finding the entry on the subject and them check the start of that file; for [`:help :command`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html):

```
This subject is introduced in sections |05.3|, |24.7| and |40.1| of the user
manual.
```

Searching the file for [the 40.1 section](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_40.txt.html#40.2):

```
The <f-args> keyword contains the same information as the <args> keyword,
except in a format suitable for use as function call arguments.  For example:
>
    :command -nargs=* DoIt :call AFunction(<f-args>)
    :DoIt a b c
```

It shows something similar to what you guessed: calling separated functions, but with arguments.

Unfortunately I couldn't find anything about this subject on the blogs mentioned above.

As was mentioned on the question comments, the alternative is to use `\` as line continuation, but that usually leads to clumsy and hard-to-read/edit code.

There is a pattern that I have seen many times when people use the function approach and the [`<bang>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Cbang%3E) which is made available by `:command`:

```
command -bang MyCmd call MyFunction(<bang>0, arg2)
```

This is useful because `<bang>` expands on `!` or nothing, so concatenating it with `0` makes it easier to check with an `if`.

---

**Edit:**

As mentioned by Carpetsmoker, it is better to use script-local `s:a_function()` instead of a global `AFunction()`, as it is more localized and doesn't appear in tab completions and such.

Comment: Instead of a global `AFunction()` I like to use `s:a_function()` − this is more localized  and doesn't appear in tab completions and such...